# Finding sum conditionally mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

i have a table **test** containing columns as:

> 1. id
> 2. amt
> 3. date(yyyy-mm-dd)

and values as

```
1  10  2017-08-09
1  20  2017-08-10
2  10  2017-09-11
```

Now i need to sum all the amt for a particular id only if the `MONTH(date) = value1 AND YEAR(date) = value2`.

I tried the following but am not getting the desired result.

```
@value1 = 8
@value2 = 2017
@id = 1

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = @value1 AND YEAR(date)= @value2        
                THEN test.amt 
                ELSE 0 END) netAmt
  FROM test 
 WHERE id = @id
```

Desired result should be 30 . However i get 0 .
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT MONTH(date), YEAR(date) FROM test` to see if those are outputted as expected?

Comment: I just tested your query, it works on MariaDB. Check your input type/values

Comment: The query looks fine. Is the column called `date` of datatype `date`? I am asking because you specify a format ('yyyy-mm-dd'), but dates are just values and have no particular format.

Comment: Why don't you just filter in the where clause?

Comment: FILTERING in Where clause gives null values

Comment: @fancyPants: I guess to get a zero when there are only records with non-matching dates for the ID. (While no row returned indicates that one was mistaken with the ID.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: the date was of type Varchar . However changing it to Date didn't matter too.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord: yes i did test that

Comment: What do you get when you add `SUM(amt)` to your select list? What do you get when you add `COUNT(*)` to it?

Comment: i think there is some error in using the variables. Desired result is achieved on entering hard coded values for value1 value2 and id

Answer (score 0):

this may help you,

```
select sum(amt) as amt from test where month(date)=8 and year(date)='2017' and id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

sql like this:

```
select sum(amt) from test where date like '2017-08%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
SET @value1 = 8;
SET @value2 = 2017;
SET @id = 1;

select sum(`amt`) as total from test where `id` = @id and MONTH(`date`) = @value1 AND YEAR(`date`)= @value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on MySql Workbench and was trying to select three set statements all at a time.

The result was that only the 1st set statement was being set. Executing them separately worked.